# TYPO3 tt_news. How to output field in attribute in template?

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript

I tried to do it like this:

```
<div class="<!-- ###AUTHOR### --><!-- ###AUTHOR### -->">
```

And this:

```
<div class="###AUTHOR###">
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

woops, second variant works, but I write this wrong